# python: How to create set out of unicode objects

Tags: python

i have this following code in python/Django

```
movie_obj = Movies.objects.all() //assume there are 2 movies
for movie in movie_obj
    movie.genre                 //genre = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True)
```

will print like

```
Drama, Sci-Fi, Thriller      //genre of movie_1

Biography, Drama, Music      // genre of movie_2
```

I want to create Set of movie's genre like

```
genre_set = Set([Drama, Sci-fi, thriller, Music, Biography])
```

**The problem:**
movie.genre is an **unicode object**. Since movie_obj is considered as a single unicode object.

how can i get individual genre from movie_obj, so that i can make List and therby Set.

Comment: `genres = movie.genre.split(',').strip()` to get a list of individual genres

Comment: Your database is set up weirdly.  `genre` should be a ManyToMany field to a Genre table...

Comment: what should be is not always correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = unicode('bla, blee, bla, blue')
>>> a
u'bla, blee, bla, blue'
>>> a.split(', ')
[u'bla', u'blee', u'bla', u'blue']
>>> set(a.split(', '))
set([u'blee', u'blue', u'bla'])
```

For each genre, you can split them on the coma, and then have a list to do what you want, then you can convert it into a set, if you'd like so

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your issue. But this should work:

```
genre_groups = Movies.objects.values_list('genre', flat = True) #output: ['Drama, Sci-Fi, Thriller', 'Biography, Drama, Music']
genres = [ agroup.split(",") for agroup in genre_groups ] #output: ['Drama', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'Biography', 'Drama', 'Music']
genres_set = set(genres) #output = set('Drama', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller', 'Biography', 'Music')
```

**EDIT**: my bad, the 2nd step returns an array of arrays. I'll see how to solve it an elegant way

Alternative step 2 and 3:

```
genres_set = {}
for agroup in genre_groups:
    genres_set |= set(agroup.split(","))
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically unicode strings can be members of a set, you can actually have sets that mix unicode strings and non-unicode strings.

```
be_mixed = {u'unicode','non-unicode'}

>>> type(be_mixed)
<type set>
>>> be_mixed
set{['non-unicode',u'unicode']}
```

Thus you can ignore the issue of whether or not the string is unicode.  If you try to

be_mixed = {u'unicode','non-unicode','unicode'}

You will find that be_mixed only has two members still.

In 2.7 the non-unicode representation of unicode will persist.  I think but am not sure that in 3.+ the members will both be unicode